# How to create a post request in flutter - GetConnect

Tags: flutter, api, rest, flutter-getx

I am creating a flutter app using [GetX](https://pub.dev/packages/get), for making server connections I am using **GetConnect**, I successfully integrated the Get Request but I am unable to integrate **Post Request**

Here is the piece of code:

```
const _baseUrl = 'https://support.instagram.com/';  // Dummy api url and key
const Map<String, String> _mapHeaders = {
  "ISG-API": "ZMWFDK83NMDF7NM5DF23FI0DBUJ"
};


class ApiService extends GetConnect {

 Future<TicketReply> submitTicketReply(String ticketId, String tktreply) async {

 String apiUrl = '${_baseUrl}/supportreply';
 var body = {
   'tktid': ticketId,
   'tktreply': tktreply,
 };

final response = await post(
  apiUrl,
  body,
  headers: _mapHeaders,
);
print('response: ${response.body}');
if (response.statusCode == 200) {
  return TicketReply.fromJson(response.body);
} else {
  return Future.error(response.statusText!);
}
}
}
```

Kindly guide me how to make a successful post request using getconnect

Comment: Seems alright! What's the issue? And what's the response?

Comment: While the parameters are submitting to server, the params are getting null, so that I am getting null response in return.

Comment: Which parameters?

Comment: ticketId & tktReply

Comment: Can you confirm by printing "body" that the request is sending the data properly

Answer (score 0):

You should add the decoder to the request like so

```
await post(
  apiUrl,
  body,
  headers: _mapHeaders,
  decoder: (resbody) => TicketReply.fromJson(resbody),
);
```